# How to solve TypeScript object undefined error while using object of model classes?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular12

I have an object of a class. This object is getting data from an API. While accessing this object in the HTML, I'm getting the error TS2532.
Here's the code--

```
export interface TgtInfo{
    
         Month:  string;
         SerTarget?: number;
         IFCTarget?: number;
         EmailTarget?: number;
         PSFTarget?: number;
         SMRTarget?: number;
         SerAch?: number;
         IFCAch?: number;  
         EmailAch?: number;
         PSFAch?: number;
         SMRAch?: number;
    }
```

COMPONENT TS FILE

```
 TGTData?: TgtInfo;

 this.apiService.getTargetAchivement(this.searchObj).subscribe((data: any) => {
            if(data){
            this.TGTData = data ;
            }
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
```

COMPONENT HTML FILE

```
<h2>{{TGTData?.SMRTarget | number }}%</h2>
```

Comment: If you're using classes to represent data sent to you from an API you're doing it wrong

Comment: then how should I do it ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@erVikas1/how-to-design-a-typescript-model-for-response-returned-by-httpclient-library-in-angular-a5e7f6c6b110 correct way of representing data from your API

Comment: @Vikas provides the idiomatic and simple solution. Also note that a type assertion (`data as TgtInfo`) is not a type conversion or cast but simply tells TS that a value is of the type asserted which in this case is false. There is no such capability in the language.

Comment: as suggested, I used an interface and removed (data as TgtInfo) but still getting the error.

Comment: you should use interface you dont need class

Comment: I did use interface and still getting the error.

Comment: if you create anything in angular that isnt assigned directly or in the constructor can be possibly undefined, you need to check for that in code and in views

Answer (score 0):

you can add question mark like this:
`<h2>{{TGTData?.SMRTarget | number }}%</h2>`

and if you want to give it default value you can do it like this:

```
<h2>{{TGTData?.SMRTarget | number || 0}}%</h2>
```

Comment: tried it. doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Error Code TS2532 just means that your object `TGTData`is possibly undefined -  obviously this makes sense when you consume api-data. It is thrown because angular trys to render the view but there is no value assigned to `TGTData`

The most elegant solutions is to use the `?`operator from angular template syntax. The `?`stops evaluating if the `TGTData` is `null` or `undefined`

You can also wrap your code block with an *ngIf what i would not recommend:

```
<h2 *ngIf="TGTData">{{TGTData.SMRTarget | number }}%</h2>
```

Just a side question, why do you use a class and not an interface?

Regards

Jan

Comment: Thanks. As suggested, I used an interface and did use the `?` operator  but still getting the error.

Comment: Then we need more of your code or the full error message